# how to find series inductance of a transformer

Tags: power-electronics

I'm designing feedback loop compensator for inverter. here i have H bridge, output transformer and output capacitor. it is just like dc dc converter for inverter so i needed to know How to calculate series inductance of a transformer

Comment: What is your numerical or technical starting point?

Comment: i did not get you Mr. andy

Comment: What inductance do you need. What current is it rated at. These are numbers.

Comment: transformer is 1:33, input is PWM unipolar pulse, current rating is 80A for 1kVA transformer, input is about 7.5V and output is 230V(aprox.)

Comment: Andy aka can you please reply me

Comment: Are you talking about leakage inductance, magnetization inductance or some external inductance? Also a circuit diagram would be needed to understand further.

Comment: assume i have dc dc converter, in that inductance is series and capacitor is parallel right ?, so instead of inductance i have transformer where filter capacitor is parallel with secondary winding, now i want know how transformer will act as series inductance and how to calculate it

Comment: A perfect transformer won't have any inductance unless there is inductance applied at the primary. An imperfect transformer will have a little leakage inductance but this is due to mainly how it is built and not something that can be relied upon numerically.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**

1. What you have to know is the transformer rating.
2. Let's say the current rating is 10A for example.
3. short circuit the secondary but measure the current through the short.
4. You will need a phase angle meter such as an Arbiter 928A
5. Energize the primary with a voltage source being careful not to exceed the 10 amps on the secondary
6. Put the voltage channel A of the arbiter across the voltage element and measure the current using channel B of the arbiter. The arbiter will show the current with a positive lag angle theta by default. Say we get 45 degrees. This means that the voltage on channel A is 0 degrees and the current on channel B is 360-45=315 degrees. Say it took 10 volts to do this and the current in the primary is 2 amps. Z = 10 < 0 degrees / 2 < -45 degrees = 5 ohms < 45 degrees.

**Theory**

Z = V/I, its the **LAW**!!

Where I = the current through the primary.
Where V = the voltage across the primary.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIzb1N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>